# How do I calculate how many distinct / unique products are available in multiple or all U.S. states?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to determine how many distinct products are available in multiple or all countries. (I am going to focus on 3 U.S. states, WA, OR and CA)

For an example, I have a table that looks like this:

| Product | State |
| --- | --- |
| First | WA |
| First | CA |
| First | CA |
| Second | WA |
| Second | OR |
| Second | CA |
| Second | OR |
| Third | OR |
| Third | WA |
| Third | WA |
| Third | WA |
| Fourth | WA |
| Fourth | CA |
| Fourth | OR |
| Fourth | CA |

From the table, I have 4 unique products, and 3 unique states. Using dax, I want to find the unique products that are available in all 3 states.

The output output should show 2, for product Second and Fourth since they have cover states WA, CA and OR.

I've attempted doing this with

```
dax = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(table1[product],filter(table1,[state] IN {"WA","CA","OR"}))
```

but it returns a maximum number of distinct products for whichever state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
Measure4 = 
VAR _0 =
    CONCATENATEX ( VALUES ( 'fct'[State] ), fct[State], ",", fct[State], DESC )
VAR _1 =
    COUNTX ( VALUES ( 'fct'[State] ), fct[State] )
VAR _2 =
    IF ( _1 > 2, _0, BLANK () )
RETURN
    _2
```

[image: Solution]

**`Edit`**

You can create a following measure after the measure above to give you the desired result in a card

```
newMeasure =
COUNTX (
    FILTER (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            SUMMARIZE (
                fct,
                fct[Product],
                "test", CONCATENATEX ( VALUES ( fct[State] ), fct[State], ",", fct[State], DESC )
            ),
            "test2", [Measure4]
        ),
        [test2] <> BLANK ()
    ),
    [test2]
)
```

Comment: This seems to be going in the right direction I am looking for. How would I output just the number of unique products that are available in WA, OR and CA? 

For an example, Fourth and Second would be 2 unique products that fulfill the category so the output should be 2 if I were to show it on a Card in Power BI.

Comment: Edited as requested

Comment: Thank you! This seems to work. I will need to "reverse engineer" this to understand how all of this works but I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with INTERSECT function (from your sample data measure return One, because product Fourth dont have 'OR'):

```
 dax = 
var __WA_product = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(table1[product]), filter(table1,[state] = "WA"))
var __CA_product = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(table1[product]), filter(table1,[state] = "CA"))
var __OR_product = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(table1[product]), filter(table1,[state] = "OR"))
return
countrows( INTERSECT(INTERSECT(__WA_product, __CA_product ), __OR_product ))
```

Comment: I fixed my example table so produce Fourth includes 'OR'. There was a typo.

The dax you provided does not resolve my issue. I still get the same problem where it shows 4 because second contains 4 values that have WA, OR or CA.